# mySQL-Query not working: just invoicenumbers starting with xyz%

Tags: mysql

would appreciate some help. MySQL is ignoring that I ask just for rows where the invoicenumber starts with some characters. No error message. I just get all invoices as I have asked for.

I added `OR 'orders_billing'.'rechnungsnummer' LIKE 'xy%' OR 'orders_billing'.'rechnungsnummer' LIKE 'ab%'`

And this part does not work. Could anybody give me a hint, please?

```
SELECT     "orders_billing"."billing_id",
                            "orders_total_local"."orders_id",
                            "orders_billing"."rechnungsnummer",
                            "orders_total_local"."value" as versandkosten,
                            "orders_billing"."rechnung_crdate",
                            "orders_billing"."billing_company",
                            "orders_billing"."billing_address_id" as customers_id,
                            "orders_billing"."billing_name",
                            "orders_billing"."billing_country",
                            "orders_billing"."delivery_country",
                            "orders_billing"."rechnung_pdf",
                            "orders_products_local"."final_price",
                            "orders_products_local"."products_tax",
                            "orders_local"."currency"
                    FROM    "orders_billing"
                    LEFT JOIN("orders_products_local","orders_local","orders_total_local")
                            ON( "orders_products_local"."orders_id" = "orders_billing"."orders_id" AND 
                                "orders_local"."orders_id"          = "orders_billing"."orders_id" AND 
                                "orders_total_local"."orders_id"    = "orders_billing"."orders_id" 
                                ) 
                    WHERE "billing_id" > '23' && "billing_id" < '27'
                    OR "orders_total_local"."class"    = 'ot_shipping' 
                    OR "orders_billing"."rechnungsnummer" LIKE 'ABC%' 
                    OR "orders_billing"."rechnungsnummer" LIKE 'XYZ%'
```

Comment: Learn about operator precedence `WHERE ("billing_id" > '23' && "billing_id" < '27'
                    OR "orders_total_local"."class"    = 'ot_shipping' )
                    AND ("orders_billing"."rechnungsnummer" LIKE 'ABC%' 
                    OR "orders_billing"."rechnungsnummer" LIKE 'XYZ%')` First OR could be AND its hard to tell

Comment: This is absolutely right and was the solution to my problem. (Thank You!!!)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
WHERE "billing_id" > '23' AND "billing_id" < '27'
                    OR ("orders_total_local"."class"    = 'ot_shipping') 
                    OR ("orders_billing"."rechnungsnummer" LIKE 'ABC%' )
                    OR ("orders_billing"."rechnungsnummer" LIKE 'XYZ%')
```

Another way,

```
WHERE "billing_id" > '23' && "billing_id" < '27'
                        || ("orders_total_local"."class"    = 'ot_shipping') 
                        || ("orders_billing"."rechnungsnummer" LIKE 'ABC%' )
                        || ("orders_billing"."rechnungsnummer" LIKE 'XYZ%')
```